# Unknown column 'a.revenue' in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, database, having-clause

```
SELECT 
      a.seller_id seller_id
FROM 
     (SELECT seller_id, sum(price) revenue 
      FROM Sales GROUP BY seller_id) as a
HAVING 
     a.revenue = min(a.revenue)
```

The error I got is `Unknown column 'a.revenue' in 'having clause'`
I would like to get the sellers that has minimum revenue. It seems like I could neither use `where` nor `having`. What should I do?

Below is the table structure, the column name 'price' is actually revenue for each product.

```
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| seller_id | product_id | buyer_id | sale_date  | quantity | price |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| 1         | 1          | 1        | 2019-01-21 | 2        | 2000  |
| 1         | 2          | 2        | 2019-02-17 | 1        | 800   |
| 2         | 2          | 3        | 2019-06-02 | 1        | 800   |
| 3         | 3          | 4        | 2019-05-13 | 2        | 2800  |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
```

The expected output is

```
+-------------+
| seller_id   |
+-------------+
| 2           |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Could you show me your table structure?

Comment: if you looking for minimum price value,then directly use single SELECT...

Comment: @AntonyJack He's not. He's looking for a minimum sum of `price` per group.

Comment: what output are you expecting...???

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is first calculate the minimum revenue in subquery and use it to check which all sellers have their revenue equal to minimum revenue.

Something like this

```
select 
  seller_id,sum(price) 
from sales 
group by seller_id 
having sum(price) = (select sum(price) from sales group by seller_id order by 1 limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`revenue` is only available in the subquery. You need to "export" it to the outer query's results in order for the outer query's `HAVING` to have access to it.

```
SELECT 
      a.seller_id seller_id, a.revenue revenue ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I can't test it but, I think something like this could work

```
Select * from (
SELECT a.seller_id seller_id FROM (SELECT seller_id, sum(price) revenue FROM Sales) as a) as res GROUP BY res.seller_id  having res.revenue = min(res.revenue)
```